# WPF MVVM: ICommand Binding to controls

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, commandbinding

I've totally lost in the command binding that is used in MVVM. How should I bind my object to the window and/or its command to the control to get method called on the `Button` `Click`?

Here is a `CustomerViewModel` class:

```
public class CustomerViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    RelayCommand _saveCommand;
    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_saveCommand == null)
            {
                _saveCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.Save(), param => this.CanSave);
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SaveCommand");
            }
            return _saveCommand;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        ...
    }

    public bool CanSave { get { return true; } }

    ...
```

`ViewModelBase` implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface
Here is how `Button` is bound to the command:

```
<Button Content="Save" Margin="3" Command="{Binding DataContext.Save}" />
```

An instance of the `CustomerViewModel` is assigned to the `DataContext` of the window that contains a `Button`.

The given example is not working: I've put break point into the `Save` method but execution doesn't pass to the method. I've saw a lot of examples (on the stackoverflow too), but can't figure out how binding should be specified.

Please advise, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S. Probably I need to specify `RelativeSource` in the Button binding... something like this:

```
 Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.Save, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
```

but which type should be specified for ancestor?

Comment: Are there any binding errors in the program's output? Binding errors often go undetected. You should also try Snoop. It's a tool that attaches to your running application and can also spot binding errors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to bind directly to the Save method.  This is not how to do it.

Assuming that you have set the DataContext of your View to an instance of CustomerViewModel, this is how you bind to the SaveCommand:

```
<Button Content="Save" Margin="3" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
```

You do not have to call `NotifyPropertyChanged("SaveCommand");`.

Comment: Many thanks!

ingenious simple :) Now I got how does it work :)

P.S. I would add a score to the answer but don't have enough points yet.